# Does <iframe> support javascript in design mode?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Does the HTML nodes in `<iframe>` support javascript in design mode? For the following code, dialog doesn't pop up when I click the `<span>`. My browser is FF 16.0.2. Is there any way to get an alert when clicking the span?

```
<html>
  <body >
    <iframe id="myeditor" style="width:500px; height:170px;"></iframe><br><br>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      editor = document.getElementById("myeditor").contentWindow;
      editor.document.designMode="on";
      editor.document.open();

      editor.document.write('head <span onclick="alert(1)" style="border: solid 1px #666">click me</span> tail');

      editor.document.close();
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Thanks for reading here. :D

Comment: What's design mode in HTML? Which IDE are you using?

Comment: Works for me in Chrome 23.0.1271.64: http://jsfiddle.net/HP8Ue/

Comment: Re design mode: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Rich-Text_Editing_in_Mozilla and http://blog.whatwg.org/the-road-to-html-5-contenteditable.

Comment: Never heard of design mode before either but [apparently it exists](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.designMode)

Comment: @AllanKimmerJensen Mozilla documents that as well, and even Chrome defines that property.

Comment: @Allan: According to what I've read (see the links) both attributes (`designMode` and `contentEditable`) are implemented in all browsers. It was first implemented by IE, but is now available in other browsers.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, guys. Design mode is for WYSIWYG.

Comment: @JanDvorak It appears I was wrong, thanks for updating me :-)

Comment: `designMode` has existed for 12 years in IE and 9 years in Firefox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Event Handling Disabled**
>
> A further difference for Mozilla is that once a document is switched to designMode, all events on that particular document are disabled. Once designMode is turned off however (as this now seems possible in Mozilla 1.5) the events become active again.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Rich-Text_Editing_in_Mozilla).

Comment: Just wanted to mention this... so, it's important to point out that this has nothing to do with iframes.

Comment: Thank you. It seems that there is no way to listen the event in FF designMode.

Comment: Thank you. It seems that there is no way to listen the event in FF designMode on.